# Segmentation fault in "where-statement" using ifort 19.0 and gfortran 9.1 compiler

Tags: fortran, segmentation-fault, gfortran

My code runs without errors using the gfortran 9.1 compiler but throws a segmentation fault using the ifort 19.0 compiler.

Is this a compiler bug or am I using the "where-statement" wrong?

```
program where_test
use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: dp => REAL64

real(dp), allocatable :: test_array(:,:,:), test_array2(:,:,:)

allocate(test_array(128,128,128), test_array2(128,128,128))

test_array = 5.0_dp    
test_array(64,:,:) = 10.0_dp
test_array2 = 0.0_dp

where(test_array == 10.0_dp) 
    test_array2 = 1.0_dp
elsewhere
    test_array2 = 10.0_dp
end where

write(*,*) minval(test_array), maxval(test_array)
write(*,*) minval(test_array2), maxval(test_array2)

end program where_test
```

The gfortran 9.1 compiler gives the expected output:

5.0000000000000000        10.000000000000000

1.0000000000000000        10.000000000000000

[The ifort 19.0 yields a segmentation fault in line 12 (beginning of where statement):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2WOZ.png)

Comment: Please do not link to images of text content, copy-paste the content directly.

Comment: Please don't include the compiler output as an image, but as text.  This helps readability/accessibility.

Comment: Else, I see nothing wrong with the code in terms of bug, apart that equality testing for floating point number is in general not what you want (it depends on roundoff and is thus unreliable, testing for "closeness" is best).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a stack overflow. gfortran, by default, puts temporary array copies on the heap, but ifort's default is to put them on the stack, which is limited in size.

Add the option `-heap-arrays` and it will run just as in gfortran.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Steve. Is there a reason for this behaviour, e.g. better permormance in most applications?

Comment: Yes - performance. It is a single instruction to allocate stack data, hundreds or thousands to do it on the heap. Back when data tended to be smaller this wasn't as much an issue, but it is nowadays. On Linux you can at least adjust the stack size with a shell command - on Windows it's a property of the executable. The maximum stack size is also much smaller than maximum data size in the 64-bit world. ifort generally avoids defaults that hurt performance on "ordinary" programs, though this is a situation where I think the default should now change.

Comment: Also, deallocation of stack data is effectively free, heap data again needs hundreds of instructions to free (and one has to keep track of what needs to be freed and make sure it gets freed at the right time.)

Comment: It's amusing that I get to tell someone they have a stack overflow on StackOverflow....